# Ayuda en laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Quisiera saber Como puedo colocar fechas a los nombres de los documentos de excel en laravel para poder saber en que dia se exporto el archivo agradeceria su colaboracion

Comment: ¿cuál es el código que has intentado? O al menos el código implicado donde deseas hacer la modificación.

Comment: solo es este pedacito ya q el codigo es demasiado grande pero en este fragmento lo quiero colocar Excel::create('Filtro de Precebo por Granja y Lote', function($excel) use($gr, $lote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer cualquier cosa con fechas te recomiendo que uses Carbon.

A la hora de crear el nombre del excel le añades la fecha y listo.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$name ='Filtro de Precebo por Granja y Lote'.Carbon::now();
o
$name ='Filtro de Precebo por Granja y Lote'.Carbon::now('Europe/Madrid');

Excel::create($name , function($excel) use($gr, $lote)
```

[Documentacion Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Porque no aplicas a concatenar la fecha

```
Excel::create('Filtro de Precebo por Granja y Lote'.date('Ymd'), function($excel) use($gr, $lote)
```

Donde `date('Ymd')`te devuelve la cadena de AñoMesDía.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: Si, y como dice que utilizas Laravel, puede usar Carbon tambien: `Carbon\Carbon::today()`